# How to create plain DOM element with React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a plain HTML string as a string in my javascript code using React, e.g.:

```
const htmlString = '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>'
```

Now, I want to set the `className` attribute of the `<h1>` element programmatically within a method of one of my React components.

I would usually go and do this:

```
let htmlElement = document.createElement('div')
htmlElement.innerHTML = htmlString
```

Then I could go and call the following:

```
htmlElement.getElementByTagName('h1').className = 'description-heading'
```

However, with React I don't have access to `document`, so I can't call `createElement`. How can I solve this issue with React?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html does this help?

Comment: What's the final purpose? You could easily use the JSX syntax to represent the element markup and create it too in one shot. Are you taking the markup as an input from somewhere?

Comment: @HazardouS that's basically the case. the html is generated programmatically, but I need to adjust CSS classes afterwards...

Comment: @HazardouS any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a parser for this, or use an [existing one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react).